# Line length for C code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, formatting

When formatting C code in VS Code, it seems to insist on wrapping at 80 characters. I figured there would be a setting to control this, but I can't for the life of me find one.

Does anyone know how to set the column width for wrapping C code in VS Code?

Comment: Did you try: `Tools-> Options-> Text Editor-> language-> General-> Word wrap` ?

Comment: @daShier This is VS Code, not VS. But yes, I've tried the word wrap option in VS Code and it only applies when word wrap is enabled (which is a separate thing to line length when formatting code).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I just ran VS Code (I don't use it much) and typed in a few very long lines in a  test.c file without any problem.  I'll try to find out if there's a way to export the settings so we can look for what is different.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using the C/C++ extension then add the following to your settings.json

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ ColumnLimit: 0 }",
```

This will make it so that when formatting the file it will not automatically wrap lines.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My setting is `"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "WebKit"` - how does that fit with the suggested `ColumnLimit`? What is the Syntax, where is the doc?

Comment: `"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: WebKit, ColumnLimit: 100 }",` seems to be the way to go.